# Looking for advice regarding different users module

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, authentication, servlets

There is Administrator, Staff and Client (User Types). I am using eClipse + Tomcat 9. The registration and login system for the aforementioned user types are approximately same and they are using one common package.

What you suggest as to how I deal them? I mean as separate 3 projects in eclipse or better to deal them as one project? What are pros and cons of dealing every user as separate project or as one project?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly will understand System.

We can treat Administrator, Staff and Client as roles for your project. Registration and Login systems same for all user types.

> I mean as separate 3 projects in eclipse or better to deal them as one
> project?

If it is Role based system better to use in single project. As feature wise, they are sharing common package and same user experience with respect to Registration and login.

> What are pros and cons of dealing every user as separate project or as
> one project?

If we keep in a single project, will only have to keep checks for user types. Apart from that we can reuse the exiting code for all user types. It will ease to maintain code base and easy to write test for the same as well.

Thanks. Happy Coding!